# How do I fix snap browsers in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Tags: firefox, chromium

How do I fix snap browers in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?  Firefox will not launch.  I tried removing and reinstalling.  Also, I installed Chromium and it would not launch.  I have a new install of 22.04 in a dual boot with Windows 10.  I have been able to install Timeshift and create a backup.  I can access settings okay so what can I do to get a working browser?

Comment: define "fix" - snaps are all sort of locked and sandboxed, so you either have to install a snap and disable updates on them (not recommended) or file bugs against the snaps wherever upstream reports go for it and then the snaps need updated once fixes are available.

Comment: Launch times for snap apps are long. Did you give Firefox and Chromium enough time to launch?

Comment: I found out that uninstalling the default Firefox and installing Firefox 101 beta fixes the issue.

Comment: See here https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04 or elsewhere for far better approaches.